# PHP Preventing kinds of files being uploaded, removing spaces in uploaded files

Tags: php, nginx, upload, web

i'm looking for some help with my PHP script for my website, i'm teaching a small class of pupils, and some have asked, how exactly we actually put it on the internet? So i made a php upload script so they can upload it to my website to share with their friends.

I have two problems:

1) How exactly do i make it so when somebody uploads a file it will remove all of the spaces in the uploaded files name?
2) How exactly do i make it so i can prevent people uploading certain kinds of files? (like jpg files, png files ext)

Heres my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
      <meta name="viewport" content=
         "width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
      <title>
         File Upload
      </title>
      <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="icons/favicon.png" />
      <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type=
         "text/css" />
      <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="js/bootstrap-filestyle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src=
         "https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"
         type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src=
         "https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"
         type="text/javascript"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container" style=
         "margin-top: 30px;margin-bottom: 30px">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">
               <h2 style="text-align: center;">
                  <strong>Alydus.net File Upload</strong>
               </h2>
               <div class="well">
                  <form role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method=
                     "post">
                     <h3>
                        Upload a file
                     </h3>
                     <hr />
                     <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                           <div class="form-group">
                              <input type="file" name="example" id="input01"
                                 class="filestyle" data-buttonbefore="true" />
                              <?php 
                                 $dir_upload = '/usr/local/nginx/html/upload/uploads/'; 
                                 $max_size = 200000000;

                                 $file = $_FILES['example'];

                                 if ($file['size'] <= $max_size && $file['size'] > 0) {
                                         $new_name = time() . '-' . $file['name'];
                                         $copied = copy($file['tmp_name'], $dir_upload . $new_name);

                                         if ($copied) {
                                                 print("Successfully uploaded to server, you can download/view the uploaded file now.");
                                         } else {
                                                 print("An unknown error has occurred.");
                                         }
                                 } else {
                                         print("");
                                 }
                                 ?>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-2">
                           <div class="form-group">
                              <button type="submit" class=
                                 "btn btn-primary">Upload File</button> <a href=
                                 "http://alydus.net/upload/uploads/<?=$new_name; ?>"
                                 class="btn btn-primary" role=
                                 "button">Download/view uploaded file</a>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </form>
               </div>
               <div class="container" style=
                  "margin-top: 30px;margin-bottom: 30px">
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="span12">
                        <div class="well">
                           <form role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data"
                              method="post">
                              <h3>
                                 Instructions
                              </h3>
                              <hr />
                              <div class="row">
                                 <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <div>
                                       <ul>
                                          <li>Click choose file
                                          </li>
                                          <li>Select your file you'd like to
                                             upload
                                          </li>
                                          <li>Click upload file once
                                          </li>
                                          <li>When the file is finished you
                                             should see a complete message, then
                                             click view/download uploaded file
                                          </li>
                                          <li>You can then copy the link and send
                                             it to anyone so they can view your
                                             images, your html files, and even
                                             download your files!
                                          </li>
                                       </ul>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </form>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="container" style=
                     "margin-top: 30px;margin-bottom: 30px">
                     <div class="row">
                        <div class="span12">
                           <div class="well">
                              <form role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data"
                                 method="post">
                                 <h3>
                                    Files Uploaded
                                 </h3>
                                 <hr />
                                 <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                                       <div style=
                                          'width: 1015px; height: 2500px; overflow: hidden;'>
                                          <center>
                                             <iframe style=
                                                'width: 1015px; height: 2500px;' src=
                                                'http://alydus.net/upload/uploads/index.php'>
                                             </iframe>
                                          </center>
                                       </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
                                    <center>
                                       © <?php echo date("Y"); ?> Copyright
                                       Alydus.net
                                    </center>
                                 </div>
                              </form>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

You can view it in action at http://alydus.net/upload

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/)?) to work out generalities. Then, when you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own question

Answer (score 1):

> 1) How exactly do i make it so when somebody uploads a file it will
>   remove all of the spaces in the uploaded files name?

This can be achieved by using `preg_replace("/\s/g", "", $new_name);`
Example which replaces every space by a `T`. https://regex101.com/r/tR8uJ7/1

> 2) How exactly do i make it so i can prevent people uploading certain
>   kinds of files? (like jpg files, png files ext)

Before moving the uploaded file you can check the file extension via a regex e.g. `preg_match("/^(.*)\.(png|jpeg|exe)$/", $filename);` This regex match any string beginning with any character and ends with either .png, .jpg or .exe. https://regex101.com/r/tJ7tH6/1

You may adjust it to your needs. If you're not familiar with regex search the web for it - there a lot of tutorials out there.
***Keep in mind that file extensions can be faked easily.***

**Here we go with a sample** *It's not tested but should work, otherwise tell me what's not working.*

```
                            <?php 
                                $dir_upload = ''; 
                                $max_size = 200000000;
                                $regexAllowedFileExtensions = "/^(.*)\.(png|jpeg|exe)$/";

                                $file = $_FILES['example'];

                                if ( $file['size'] <= $max_size && $file['size'] > 0) {
                                    if (preg_match($regexAllowedFileExtensions, $file['name']))
                                    {
                                          $filename_temp = str_replace(" ", "", $file['name']);
                                          $new_name = time() . '-' . $filename_temp;

                                          $copied = move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], __DIR__ . '/' . $new_name);

                                          if ($copied) {
                                              print("Successfully uploaded to server, you can download/view the uploaded file now.");
                                          } else {
                                              print("An unknown error has occurred.");
                                          }
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        print("The file type is not allowed.");
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    print("");
                                }
                            ?>
```

Comment: I have updated the script with a snippet that should work. See your shared html/php with above php snippet: http://www.codeshare.io/kWEnT

Comment: You may try the updated code of the codeshare link. I have replaced the copy function with move_uploaded_file http://php.net/manual/de/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: You're welcome. It was a logic issue in the regex for removing all whitespaces - instead of replacing the whitespaces only the complete string has been removed. I have changed it to str_replace and it's working locally now. I have changed the dir_upload to `__DIR__` in my local script. You may adjust it to your needs. http://www.codeshare.io/kWEnT

Comment: In this case I recommend to debug. See http://www.codeshare.io/9XctP for an example.

Comment: See line 9 to 11 for the debugging stuff. DIR is a constant provided by php which contains the full path to current directory. I recommend to var_dump each variable to analyse them for errors/typos etc.